# I asked + tense

Tags: tenses

Yesterday in class I had such an example in my book:

A: "What do you need?"
B: Just a piece of paper.
Next day: A: I asked what you...

Which option?

"I asked what you needed yesterday."?
or
"I asked what you had needed yesterday."?

Comment: If you asked today what was needed yesterday, then you should use the past perfect.

Comment: If you asked today what was needed yesterday, then you should use the past simple. Seriously  the past simple is most natural here.

Answer (score 1):

There are two basis scenarios. In the first you are referring to a question you asked yesterday, in the second you have just asked a question about your needs of yesterday.

Assume today is Friday. Possible expressions:

**Scenario 1.**  *Yesterday, I asked what you needed*. *Yesterday I asked what you (had) needed on Tuesday* (Both with and without *had* are possible, depending on context)

**Scenario 2**  *I just asked you what you (had) needed yesterday (to complete the job).* (Both with and without had are possible.)

If you simply ask a question, *I asked what you needed yesterday* putting "yesterday" at the end of the sentence, it sort of suggests scenario 2.